# Insert a greatest value (max+1)

Tags: mysql

I have a table (`foo`) where I already have a PK on `id`:

```
id      name      rank
-----------------------
 1      AAAA        2
 2      BBBB        1
```

I want to insert a new row where I know the values of column `id` and `name` and want `rank` to take a value greater than any other  value in the same column in preceding rows (similar to what `auto_increment` does for us).

i.e. if I were to add a row with `value` = `CCCC`, the `rank` column should have a value `3`. I need to do this in a compound statement if possible. I tried the following which does not work.

```
insert into foo (`name`, `rank`)
values ('CCCC', (select max(`rank`) from `foo`))
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
You can't specify target table 'foo' for update in FROM clause
```

**Note:** I would ideally like to have the `rank` column as an `auto_increment` field, but apparently that's not allowed either, since I already have a PK.

**PS:** I need to be able to execute this statement from PHP without using stored procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this first, it being derived instantly from your post:

```
INSERT INTO foo (`name`, `rank`)
SELECT 'CCCC', (MAX(`rank`) + 1) AS rank
FROM `foo`
```

Then using PDO, I think this'll work:

```php
...
$sql = "INSERT INTO foo (`name`, `rank`) SELECT ?, (MAX(`rank`) + 1) AS rank FROM `foo`"
$name = "CCCC";
$st = $pd->prepare($sql);
$st->bindValue(1, $name);

try {
    $retval = $st->execute();
} catch (PDOException $pdoex) {
...
```

Not sure if I got in syntactically correct but that should be about the gist of it ... I think

Err.. lemme know if the SQL works, at least :D

Comment: Works like a charm! The first i.e.